# Call jQuery function inside PHP if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call jQuery function if PHP condition is true, but somehow I cannot find the right solution:

**Here is my php/html code:**

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['success'])) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <script>//Here I want to call a showNotification function</script>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

**Here is my function inside of js code:**

```
showNotification: function(from, align) {
    color = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    $.notify({
        icon: "pe-7s-gift",
        message: "<b>Light Bootstrap Dashboard PRO</b> - forget about boring dashboards."
    },{
        type: type[color],
        timer: 4000,
        placement: {
            from: from,
            align: align
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How are you actually calling the function, and where are you placing the PHP portion as well as the JS portion of the code?

Comment: Well, if this is an if statement on page initialization, simply save it as a javascript variable -- then have your javascript run if said variable is true.

Comment: in your PHP code you are checking if $_GET['success'] is set, this could be set but not necessarily true, so I would also suggest something like so for belts and braces `if ( isset($_GET['success'] && $_GET['success']   ) { ... }`

Comment: Create a hidden HTML element.  Set the value of the element based on your PHP condition.  Then later, after the DOM loads, use JS to check the value of the hidden element, and proceed from there.

Comment: Hi! I think all you need to do is make sure your `showNotification` function is defined *before* you output a call to it in your PHP. So if that success condition outputs something towards the top of your page, make sure the script tag or file that defines your `showNotification` is inserted on the page before that.

Comment: You could also use ajax to post to a PHP page and check the return value that would execute a JavaScript function on success

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a client-side language (in your domain) and PHP is a server-side one. You can only include script tag in server response if your condition in server-side was satisfied.